# Unterschied postmateriell und postmaterialistisch

Tags: difference, word-choice

Im Bezug auf Werte lautet meine Frage, ob ein Unterschied zwischen *postmateriellen* und *postmaterialistischen* besteht?
*Postmateriell* wäre analog zu *materiell*, *postmaterialistisch* zu *Postmaterialismus*.
Kann man die Ausdrücke beide gleichwertig verwenden?

Comment: Was soll das sein, "postmateriell"?

Comment: @userunknown Ich hatte es auf Werte bezogen gemeint. Als postmaterielle Werte -> Werte wie Selbstverwirklichung etc.; materielle Werte -> Geld/Haus etc.

Comment: Und wieso sind das postmaterielle Werte und nicht prematerielle?

Comment: @userunknown Seit wann gibt es das Wort premateriell? Und es wird halt so genannt. Das post wird vllt. auch benutzt, da diese Werte nach den materiellen kommen (Wertewandeltheorie)

Comment: Premateriell ist so sinnlos oder sinnvoll wie postmateriell. Postmateriell unterstellt, dass es Werte nach den materiellen sind. Vielleicht meinst Du immaterielle Werte?

Comment: @userunknown Nein ich mein das genau so. Hier mal ein Artikel der BpB http://m.bpb.de/nachschlagen/datenreport-2016/226961/materialistische-und-postmaterialistische-werte

Comment: Was ist das für eine Schrottseite? Da kann man ja keine Textabschnitte markieren/kopieren! Und inhaltlich ist es Sondermüll. Außerdem kommt das Wort postmateriell gar nicht vor, also was soll der Link belegen?

Comment: @userunknown Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung ist das. Das Wort postmateriell kommt nicht vor, aber postmaterialitisch, was ursprünglich meine Frage war. Und weils du dir so wichtig ist, hier noch ein Artikel in dem "postmateriell" vorkommt: http://m.bpb.de/politik/grundfragen/deutsche-verhaeltnisse-eine-sozialkunde/138454/werte-milieus-und-lebensstile-wertewandel

Comment: Ich weiß was das ist, und die bpb ist bekannt für Schrott. Die wissen nicht wovon sie reden, wollen es aber anderen erklären. "der Mangelhypothese, nach der mit Befriedigung der grundlegenden materialistischen Bedürfnisse" - gemeint sind materielle Bedürfnisse (essen, trinken, schlafen, atmen). Und es gibt keine postmateriellen Bedürfnisse, weil die materiellen Bedürfnisse erst mit dem Tod enden. Das ist nur Phrasendrescherei da, unverstandene Phrasen jedoch. Mit jedem Satz den man da liest wird man dümmer und dümmer.

Comment: @userunknown Ja, kann sein. Die Frage habe ich aber gestellt da ich das für die Schule gebraucht hab, nich weil ich der Theorie total zustimme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76261/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-somewindowsuser).

Comment: Ja, bitter. Ich kann leider kein Schulmaterial empfehlen. Mit historischem Materialismus/dialektischem Materialismus bezeichnet man die marxistische Geschichtsauffassung. Diese ist angetreten mit dem Idealismus Schluss zu machen, der von höheren Werten/Zielen/Idealen faselt. Jetzt mit neuen Ideologien zu kommen, und zu sagen sie wären postmaterialistisch ist von geradezu fundamentaler Dummheit. Es ist ja ein Rückfall in die vormaterialistische Ideologie.

Comment: Soziologische Untersuchungen zeigen wenig überraschend, dass in Kreisen, die sich der sog. Selbstverwirklichung verschrieben haben, fast nur Mittel- und Oberschicht treffen. (Rettet die Wale!), also Kreise, die - nicht weil sie materiellen Zielen abgeschworen haben, sondern weil sie diese erreicht haben - jetzt andere Betätigungsfelder suchen. Die unteren Schichten, Arbeiter, sind in solchen Organisationen meist gar nicht vertreten, also die, die Mühe haben, die mat. Bedürfnisse zu befriedigen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*materiell* (das "post" lassen wir einfach mal weg, das heißt nur "nach") **kann** dasselbe bedeuten wie **materialistisch** - nämlich "vom Materialismus bestimmt", also getrieben z. B. vom Drang nach Besitz.

Darüber hinaus kann **materiell** auch ganz einfach "Die Materie / Das Material betreffend" bedeuten (das kann **materialistisch** nicht).

Comment: Unter Materialismus versteht man viel häufiger die philosophische Schule, die sich als Gegenpol zum Idealismus versteht und keineswegs das Streben nach Besitz in den Vordergrund stellt.